# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'module_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have an error in my project. When I want create a component and I want save it, [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHDbH.png) appears:

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'module_id' doesn't
>   have a default value.

For the details, that said:

> SQL Query:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO modules_data (name_data, content_data, type) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2)
> ```

I think the problem comes from this part of my code:

```
foreach ($module['modules_data'] as $key => $mod){
                    $content_traduit = (isset($lang[$key+1]['content_data'])) ? $lang[$key+1]['content_data'] : "";

                    $translations = [
                        $langue => ['content_data' => $content_traduit],
                        'fr' => ['content_data' => $mod['content_data']]
                    ];

                    foreach ($translations as $langage => $data) {
                        $mod->translation($langage)->set($data, ['guard' => false]);
                    }
                    $moduleData = TableRegistry::get('modules_data')->patchEntity($mod,$data);
                    TableRegistry::get('modules_data')->save($moduleData);
                }
```

Can you explain to me why this fails?

Comment: It sounds like you have a `NOT NULL` field called `module_id` but it's not given a value, did you mean to make it `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: thks for your answer, in fact, when i add the module in the hand with mysql, the module can create  but with cakephp i have this error  :/

Comment: Then you have to find the piece of code that saves the modules_data table and modify it to include the module_id field.